# How to pass a parameter to Class based views in Django?

Tags: python, django, parameter-passing, django-class-based-views, keyerror

how to pass this parameter in the class called?

This is url

```
#url
path('all-agency/<int:id>', AllAgenciesView.as_view(), name='all-agency'),
```

cbv

```
#views
class AllAgenciesView( TemplateView):
    template_name='agencies.html'

class AllAgenciesListView(ServerSideDatatableView):
 
    def get_queryset(self):
      agencies = SettingsAgency.objects.using('agency-namespace').filter(id=self.kwargs['id'])
      return  agencies
```

this is in template

```
#in anchor tag(html)
<a href="{% url 'all-agency' id=2 %}" ><div>Agencies</div></a>
```

in address bar it would look like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/all-agency/2
```

Now I want to pass the 'id' into the class based views but when i did `filter(id=self.kwargs['id')`. I Got returned `KeyError: 'id'`

i tried another way which is

```
filter(id=self.kwargs.get('id'))
```

and it returned `None` when i `print(agencies)`

another way ive tried

```
filter(id=self.request.GET.get('id'))
```

this also returned the same  `None`

Comment: can you explain how you are passing id parameter to AllAgenciesListView as url mentioned is pointing to AllAgenciesView? As you are calling AllAgenciesView only as per shared code..

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the wrong view in your paths, you should call `AllAgenciesListView` instead of `AllAgenciesView`.

Corrected version:

```
#url
path('all-agency/<int:id>', AllAgenciesListView.as_view(), name='all-agency'),
```